# Differentiate $\sum_j\sum_i a(i,j)b(i,j)$ wrt $a(i,j)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you differentiate a sum of a variable, wrt that variable, e.g. 
Find
 $\frac{dc}{da(i,j)}$ where $c = \sum_j\sum_i a(i,j)b(i,j)$.

Context:
I'm trying to find the jacobian.

Comment: Please provide more context. For instance, is this from a class you're taking, is this homework? Is there a specific question you're looking to solve, or just to know in general? It helps taylor the answers to your specific needs.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you are asking it will be just $b(i,j)$. The function $c$ is a linear function of $a$.

Comment: I wrote a really long question originally but i think it was off putting to read. i'll post it above anyway

Comment: @copper.hat how come it isn't $\sum_{i,j}b(i,j)$?

Comment: In my opinion $\frac{dc}{da(i,j)} =\sum_j\sum_i b(i,j)$

Answer (score 2):

Since there is disagreement in the comments: Take the case where $n=2$.
Then
$$c = a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{12} + a_{21}b_{21} + a_{22}b_{22}$$
So $$\frac{dc}{da_{11}} = b_{11}$$

Answer (score 0):

The original question itself is ambiguous.  In the given function, "i" and "j" are variable and asking for the derivative "wrt a(i,j)" does not specify [b]which[/b] i and j.